# Determinants with arithmetic progressions as columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove that determinants of the following form all vanish:
$$\det \begin{bmatrix} x-3 & x-4 & x-a \\ x-2 & x-3 & x-b \\ x-1 & x-2 & x-c\end{bmatrix} = 0$$
Here $a$, $b$, $c$ are three consecutive terms in an arithmetic progression.

Comment: You mean prove that the determinant of this matrix is equal to 0?

Comment: yes but based on number given on question

Comment: I dont think i understand your question. I'll try and edit your question-pls let me know if this is correct,

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: Yes this is the real question please help me because i had to sent it tomorrow

Comment: Hint: Add row 1 to row 3.

Comment: why do it have to do with some kind of properties of matrices

Comment: can anyone provide me a solution on the question I really need it in order to get some marks on my individual test

Comment: You really expect others to solve questions for **your** "individual" test??

Answer (score 5):

Adding to a row another row multiplied by any number doesn't change the determinant:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x-3 & x-4 & x-a \\
x-2 & x-3 & x-b \\
x-1 & x-2 & x-c
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & b-a \\
x-2 & x-3 & x-b \\
x-1 & x-2 & x-c
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_1\gets R_1-R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & b-a \\
0 & -1 & x-b+(x-2)(b-a) \\
x-1 & x-2 & x-c
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_2\gets R_2+(x-2)R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & b-a \\
0 & -1 & x-b+(x-2)(b-a) \\
0 & -1 & x-c+(x-1)(b-a)
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\gets R_3+(x-1)R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & b-a \\
0 & -1 & x-b+(x-2)(b-a) \\
0 & 0 & 2b-a-c
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\gets R_3-R_2
\end{align}
When is the determinant $0$?

Comment: +1, Very nice solution, I hope the OP understands it though.

Answer (score 3):

$(1,-2,1)$ is a left eigenvector associated with a zero eigenvalue, so the determinant is trivially zero since that matrix is not invertible.

Comment: +1.  In a similar vein, any AP is a linear combination of $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$, so the column space has dimension at most $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the property $$\lambda \cdot \begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
\lambda b_1 & \lambda b_2 & \lambda b_3\\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3
\end{vmatrix} ,$$ we have:
$$\begin{vmatrix} x - 3 & x-4 & x-a \\ x-2 & x-3 & x-b\\ x-1 & x-2 & x-c \end{vmatrix}=
\frac 12\cdot 
\begin{vmatrix} x - 3 & x-4 & x-a \\ 2x-4 & 2x-6 & 2x-2b\\ x-1 & x-2 & x-c \end{vmatrix}
$$

Also, we take advantage of the property which declares that adding multiples of any rows to a specific one the determinant remains invariant. We add to the second row the first row multiplied by $(-1)$ and the third row multiplied by $(-1)$. Thus, we have:
$$\begin{vmatrix} x-3 & x-4 & x-a \\ 0 & 0 &a+c - 2b \\ x-1 & x-2 & x-c \end{vmatrix}.
$$
However, $a +c =2b$, because $a,b,c$ are consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression. That means that we have a zero row, which implies that the determinant is zero!

Comment: where is the x and why is it 2b=a+c

Comment: You need to take advantage of some properties of the determinant.

Comment: I still do not understand clearly can you do the working more specifically I am very grateful if you can do it

Comment: I am still a matriculation student and I  still not understand the term that you used.Can you give me a direct answer because I really need it I am very grateful if you can do that

Comment: @MOHDEMIRASHRAF, so you're just looking for the solution right?

Comment: A nice solution IMO. Unfortunately the asker's approach may lead to an eventual deletion of the entire thread. I tried to edit and make the question clear, but there is no context, so I'm not optimistic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. I think it covers OP's level and involves fundamental properties of the determinant.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Despite being a nice problem with many different approaches, my intuition agrees (partially) that the thread will be closed, if not deleted!

Comment: why can we assume 2b=a + c is equal to zero

Comment: Take any $3$ consecutive terms $a,b,c$ of an arithmetic progression. Then it holds: $b= a + d, c = a+ 2d$, where $d$ is the constant difference (this is implied by the *definition* of the arithmetic progression). Thus, we have:
$2b = 2a + 2d$ and $a + c = a  + (a+2d) = 2a + 2d$, i.e. $2b = a+c$.

Comment: so how this can make it equal to zero

Comment: why choose second row to be factor out instead of first and third row

Comment: which property that allowed to add second row with first and third row multiplied with -1

Comment: and how to express it in term of math operation

Comment: I think you should consult your textbook about the properties of the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

$$\det \begin{bmatrix} x-3 & x-4 & x-a \\ x-2 & x-3 & x-b \\ x-1 & x-2 & x-c\end{bmatrix} = \\ (x-3) \begin{vmatrix}x-3 &x-b \\x-2 & x-c  \end{vmatrix} - (x-4)\begin{vmatrix}x-2 &x-b \\x-1 & x-c  \end{vmatrix} + (x-a) \begin{vmatrix}x-2 &x-3 \\x-1 & x-2  \end{vmatrix}$$

If a, b and c are consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression,

$a = a,\  b = a + d, \  c = a + 2d $

Solving the last 2 equations gives: $d = c-b$, $b- a = d$

Hence, $b-a = c-b$  $\implies$ $a+c = 2b$

Now try and expand $$\det \begin{bmatrix} x-3 & x-4 & x-a \\ x-2 & x-3 & x-b \\ x-1 & x-2 & x-c\end{bmatrix}$$ and use the fact that $a+c = 2b$ and see what you get

You have to make some effort here I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am not very understand about the equation invoved arithmetric progression why d is involved

Comment: d in the arithmetic progression is common difference, e.g in the AP: 1, 3, 5, the common difference is 2, make sense? Read this-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: can you show me how you expand the determinant just want to check whether it is same as me or not

Comment: Read this-https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/determinant.html.

Comment: do the determinant is really zero and how do i get a b and c

Comment: how do i get value of a b and c

Comment: What did you get for the determinant of the matrix?